# how to apply a label to the button group set in bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

the Nu html checker complains that

> The value of the for attribute of the label element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
           <label for="aptmt">select item</label>  <!-- ERROR -->
           <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="aptmt" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio1" value="0">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio1">both</label>
                        
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio2" value="2">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio2">upper</label>
                        
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio3" value="1">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio3">lower</label>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

While this causes no real issue, it does behave differently than the other labels. If the column is too wide, the button group will be right hand side to the label, while all other labels remain above the input box.

Any idea how I can connect the label `select item` to the whole group?

Comment: What do you mean by "connect... to the whole group?" Do you mean to select everything when the label is created? If so, you should be using a checkbox instead of radio

Comment: If you are just looking to get rid of that message from the HTML checker then you can just use another element for that text instead of `label`

Comment: With connect I mean that the label sticks to the button group and behaves as the other do. It is about labeling the group such as `enter sex` for the radios `male` and `female`

Comment: it it not only about the HTML checker, as I said, it creates an inconsistency in the form, since the pair of label and button group behaves differently than the pairs of label and put box.

Comment: The purpose of the label element is to focus on the associated option when you click on the label, for the most part. There are some accessibility related advantages but I don't think that is your concern. Label is for **a single** control and **not for multiple** controls as you seem to be trying. Like I said, you would use anything other than a label for that. [Refer here for more technical info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: Basically, labels are supposed to be attached to a single "input control." Hence the different behaviors. You probably want to use something like `fieldset` or similar depending on your exact needs but mostly those are for accessibility.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. Happy to accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the label element is to focus/highlight on the associated option when you click on the label, for the most part. There are some accessibility related advantages but I don't think that is your concern. Label is for a single input control and not for multiple controls as you seem to be trying. [Refer here for more technical info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Basically, labels are supposed to be attached to a single "input control." Hence the different behaviors. You probably want to use something like `fieldset` or similar depending on your exact needs but mostly those are for accessibility

Answer (score -1):

You can try wrapping the select item label as a wrapper like below. Tell me if that works. if not we'll find a different solution.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<fieldset>
           <legend for="aptmt">select item </legend>  <!-- ERROR -->
           <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="aptmt" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio1" value="0">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio1">both</label>
                        
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio2" value="2">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio2">upper</label>
                        
                <input type="radio" class="btn-check " name="apt" id="btnradio3" value="1">
                <label class="btn " for="btnradio3">lower</label>
           </div>
           </fieldset>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work.

Comment: Changed my answer using fieldset.